# DBpedia rate limiting sparql requests?

Tags: python, sparql, dbpedia, sparqlwrapper

I am running the following sparql query to DBpedia as I build a tree of a company hierarchy:

```
def get_result(sparql, parent_company):
    sparql = SPARQLWrapper('https://dbpedia.org/sparql')
    sparql.setQuery(f'''
        SELECT ?name
        WHERE {{?name dbo:parentCompany dbr:{parent_company}}}
    ''')
    sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
    gdata = sparql.query().convert()
    ...
```

I run this for each company in the organizational structure to see if they have any child companies. For larger companies (e.g., parent_company = Microsoft), this can be about 30 queries. I timed each query and most are < 1 second, but about every 5th query, it runs in about 1 min 7 secs. DBPedia's website says that it should handle up to 100 requests per second per IP address. Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: it could be some blocking nevertheless, either from the HTTP server or the backend. My suggestion, why aren't you doing a more batch like query? In SPARQL you can pass multiple values as inline data via `VALUES` keyword. For example, `SELECT ?childCompany ?parentCompany WHERE { VALUES ?parentCompany {dbr:Microsoft dbr:Apple_Inc\.} ?childCompany dbo:parentCompany ?parentCompany  }`

Comment: Or you could also try to get the whole hierarchy for a single company via a single SPARQL query

Comment: @UninformedUser - do you have a suggestion for how I could do that? I am very new to sparql and it has a very steep learning curve so I've been piecing together what I can for my current project.

Comment: depends on how you need the data, but in the end the rest is client side work anyways: `SELECT ?child ?parent WHERE {
?parent dbo:parentCompany* dbr:Microsoft .
?child dbo:parentCompany ?parent
 }` - this will give you all child-parent pairs such that Microsoft will be at the end of the chain - would this be sufficient for you?

Comment: Oh wow - yes. That is very helpful. I will take a look at that and see if I can get the results into the dictionary format that I need for my front end. Thanks!

Comment: @UninformedUser - is there a way to return only the first parent listed with this type of query? Unfortunately, dbpedia still lists companies that used to own a company so I am getting results that are no longer true.

Answer (score 0):

The DBpedia SPARQL endpoint is a fully public service, so you may well be running into delays caused by other queries from other users. You might consider spinning up your own instance of [DBpedia Snapshot](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-jnzlwa652lmjc), if you require predictably rapid responses.

[This article](https://community.openlinksw.com/t/dbpedia-usage-report-for-january-2021-through-july-2021/2716) may help you understand how DBpedia serves ad hoc queries on a worldwide basis.

Comment: I've tested this at many times of day and it is consistently throttling every 4-5 query by 1.06 seconds. The consistency leads me to think it is not due to other users unless dbpedia is consistently overloaded. This is for a school project (and one I'd like to add to my overall portfolio) so I won't be able to spin up my own Snapshot.

Comment: @nholland -- In that case, I might suggest you raise your question on the [DBpedia Community Forum](https://forum.dbpedia.org/c/support/query-dbpedia-sparql/16), and later, [post your project there](https://forum.dbpedia.org/c/dbpedia-in-use/44)